# AppBar content is not displayed for single Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

I have an `Activity` based on the scrolling `Activity` template. The `AppBar` is working as expected for the scrolling behaviour, but it does not show it's contents (Up navigation, options menu, Title).
[image: Screenshot of the activity.]

The following snippets are minimal excerpts.

`ContactEditActivity`:

```
class ContactEditActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_edit)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

    val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityContactEditBinding>(
        this,
        R.layout.activity_contact_edit
    )

    binding.contact = contact
    binding.executePendingBindings()
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem) = when (item.itemId) {
    R.id.action_settings -> {
        true
    }
    R.id.action_save -> {
        true
    }
    else -> {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_contact_edit, menu)
    return true
}
}
```

`activity_contact_edit.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="(...).activities.ContactEditActivity">
<data>
    <variable
        name="contact"
        type="(...).models.Contact" />
</data>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_contact_edit"
        app:contact="@={contact}"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

`menu_contact_edit.xml`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".activities.ContactEditActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_save"
    android:title="@string/action_save"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

`AndroidManifest.xml` (excerpt):

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ContactEditActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_contact_edit"
        android:parentActivityName=".activities.ContactActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="(...).activities.ContactActivity" />
    </activity>
```

I have cross checked my code the Developer Guide on AppBars and created a new app with the "Scrolling Activity" and compared the code. But i could not find any lead.

### Update 1

As it has been pointed out in the comments, the issue seems to be with the binding. Without the variable declaration in the layout file and the corresponding binding section in the `ContactEditActivity` the appbar renders as expected.

I added the binding section to the minimal Version of the `ContactEditActivity`.

Comment: Just a question - did you try running your app without using databinding in your activity layout?

Comment: No i didn't. I could not think of a possibility how this could interfere.

Comment: @muminers You seem to be on to something there. The problem starts when i add a binding. I'll update my question accordingly.

Comment: Sorry didn't see your previous comment - yes databinding causes some troubles applied to coordinator Layout on some devices. Don't know why, I just abbandoned using it with more complicated views. According to its unreliability it just doesn't seem like reasonable solution anymore

Comment: That's not very satisfying... But thanks anyway!